# Angular: ngFor not displaying values in the dropdown list

Tags: angular, ngfor

In my template file I have following:

```
<select class="my-class">
 <option *ngFor="let item of myObject['parameters']['items']">
 </option>
</select>
```

In component, myObject is initialized as:

```
@Input('myobject')
 set objectData(myobject: MyObject) {
 this.myObject= myobject;
 console.log(this.myObject)
}
```

In console, I can see correct value for myObject printed. myObject has an object 'parameters' which has an array 'items'.

But dropdown is empty.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You option rendering does not produce any text:

```
<option *ngFor="let item of myObject['parameters']['items']"></option>
```

So you might get empty options.

change it to

```
<option *ngFor="let item of myObject['parameters']['items']">{{item}}</option>
```

Note {{item}}, that will put your item into option, so that browser can display it.

Comment: also add `[value]="item"`

Answer (score 0):

I think you have forgot to add **`item`** in the options and you just need to use **`Safe Navigator Operator (?)`** to solve your issue.

```
  <select class="my-class">
     <option *ngFor="let item of myObject?.parameters?.items" [value]="item">{{item}}
     </option>
  </select>
```

> **P.S:** avoid using **`myObject['parameters']['items']`** this kind o syntax in the template.

I hope this helps :).

Answer (score 0):

The option tag is empty,that is why it doesn't display the options, just add something inside:

```
<select class="my-class">
 <option *ngFor="let item of myObject['parameters']['items']">
    {{item}}
 </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

The drop down value is not supplied to populate it. Your code just iterates over the items but it won't add the items to drop down to have them displayed.

```
    <div>
      <select>
         <option [ngValue]="null">--Select--</option> <!-- Default item to show -->
         <option *ngFor="let opts of data.parameters.items" [value]="opts.value">
         {{opts.name}}
         </option>
      </select>
</div>
```

**component file.**

```
 data = { parameters: {
                      items: [{name: "item1" , value:1},
                         {name: "item2", value:2},
                         {name: "item3", value:3}]
                      }};
```

Result:

[image]